# MobileFirst Platform native iOS app building have error while building .wlapp

Tags: ios, ant, ibm-mobilefirst

I am working on MobileFirst Platform version7 using ant script to build the project .war, .wlapp, .adapter.
Everything was working fine while our project was a hybrid one. Now the project is migrated to native-iOS in.

I am using following code to build .wlapp.

```
<target name="build-wlapp">
<app-builder worklightServerHost="localhost:10080"
applicationFolder="//Users/admin/Documents/workspace/NewProj/apps/Try"
environments="iOSnative"
nativeProjectPrefix="NewProj"
outputFolder="/Users/admin/Documents/workspace/NewProj/bin"/>
```

it is throwing below error:

> build.xml:66: Failed building application: The build could not be
>   completed due to invalid application-descriptor.xml.(cvc-elt.1: Cannot
>   find the declaration of element 'nativeIOSApp'.)

I am not getting where the flaw is...

Comment: is your doubt cleared with the below answer

Comment: No, I am still have doubt.

Comment: Can you please edit your `application-descriptor.xml` into the answer?

Comment: @Andrew Ferrier   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<nativeIOSApp xmlns="http://www.worklight.com/native-ios-descriptor" bundleId="com.MyTime" id="MyTime" platformVersion="7.0.0.00.20150402-2001" version="1.0">
 
 <displayName>MyTime</displayName>
 <description>MyTime</description>
 <accessTokenExpiration>3600</accessTokenExpiration>
 <userIdentityRealms/>
 
</nativeIOSApp>

Comment: @kiran as suggested, please edit it into the answer. It's very hard to read it like that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry For the Wrong answer first.

You were using the wrong code to generate the .wlapp file the ant script is below.

```
<project default="change"> 

<target name="change"> 
  <taskdef resource="com/worklight/ant/defaults.properties">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="worklight-ant-builder.jar"/>
            </classpath>
        </taskdef>   
     <native-app-builder
              sourceFolder="C:\Workspace\Test\apps\Test" DestinationFolder="bin"
              worklightServerHost="http://111.111.111.111:10080">
            </native-app-builder>
</target>
</project>
```

Comment: If it is like that then why .wlapp is creating when i am building the project using eclipse or by using mobile first server. ProjectName-iOSnative-1.0.wlapp this is the file created. but the same is not happening through ant script.

Comment: @kiran can you share your Screen shot of the project explorer

Comment: @kiran this will surely solve your problem i tested it just now and it builds my .wlapp file

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `application-descriptor.xml` you posted in your comment is complete, it looks like you have a stray semicolon after your `xmlns` declaration. That's not valid XML. Not sure how it got like that (check your source control system?), but you probably need to remove/revert it.